# Minutes between 2 dates

Tags: java

`obj.date` is a unix timestamp(long). I've checked that the date is correct, but I can't manage to get the difference in minutes between my two date objects. For example, I get 4, when I'm expecting something close to 30. Why is that?

```
Date now = new Date();
Date then = new Date((long)obj.date*1000);

int secondsbetweendates = (int) ((then.getTime()-now.getTime())/1000);

int minutesbetweendates = (secondsbetweendates/1000) % 60;
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `int minutesbetweendates = secondsbetweendates % 60;`?

Comment: You are using modulus when you should be dividing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert seconds to minutes you can divide by 60:

```
int minutesbetweendates = secondsbetweendates / 60;
```

Note that this returns an integer and *truncates* the result, meaning that only complete minutes will be counted. In other words 119 seconds will become 1 minute, not 2.

You should also be aware that it can also return a number greater than 60 if the time difference is more than one hour.